# jquery is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

iam a beginner level developer in wordpress now am trying to convert my html into wordpress..i have few jquery in my html . but after conversion my jquery seems to be not working..
it showing the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'superfish'
```

please help me to solve the issue..

Header.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <!--meta tag-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" >

    <!--Title-->
    <title><?php echo wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );?></title>

    <!--Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/colour.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/superfish.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/responsive.css" type="text/css"  media="all" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.html" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!--JavaScript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jqueryui.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jqueryui1.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/tinynav.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.uniform.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/scripts.js"></script>

    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head> 

<body id="top" class="loading">
    <div id="header-wrapper">

        <!-- BEGIN #header-border -->
        <div id="header-border">

            <!-- BEGIN #header-top -->
            <div id="header-top" class="clearfix">

                <ul class="top-left-nav clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#">Payment</a><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a><span>/</span></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="top-right-nav clearfix">
                    <li class="phone-icon">+1 919 673 3608</li>
                    <li class="email-icon">alexmm@k2asoftwaresolutions.com</li>
                </ul>

            <!-- END #header-top -->
            </div>

            <!-- BEGIN #header-content-wrapper -->
            <div id="header-content-wrapper" class="clearfix">

                <div id="logo">
                                    <h1><a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png"</a></h1>
                </div>

                <ul class="social-icons clearfix">  
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="twitter-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="facebook-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="gplus-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="pinterest-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="flickr-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="youtube-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="vimeo-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="skype-icon"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="rss-icon"></span></a></li>
                </ul>

            <!-- END #header-content-wrapper -->
            </div>

            <div id="main-menu-wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <!-- BEGIN #main-menu-wrapper -->

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                     'theme_location' => '', 
                                     'container'=> '',
                                     'container_class' => '',
                                     'container_id'    => '',
                                     'menu_class'=>'',
                                     'menu_id'=>'main-menu',
                                     'item_wrap'=>'<ul></ul>'

                                      )


             ); ?>

            <!-- END #main-menu-wrapper -->
            <div class="menu-search-button"></div>
            <form method="get" action="#" class="menu-search-form">
                    <input class="menu-search-field" type="text" 
                            onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='To search, type and hit enter';"
                            onFocus="if(this.value=='To search, type and hit enter')this.value='';" 
                            value="To search, type and hit enter" name="s" />
            </form>

            </div>
```

Script.js(from where am invoking jquery)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


// Main Menu Drop Down
jQuery('ul#main-menu').superfish({ 
    delay:       600,
    animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},
    speed:       'fast',
    autoArrows:  true,
    dropShadows: false
});

$.noConflict();
// Accordion
jQuery( ".accordion" ).accordion( { autoHeight: false } );

$.noConflict();

// Toggle
jQuery( ".toggle > .inner" ).hide();
jQuery(".toggle .title").toggle(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.inner').slideDown(200, 'easeOutCirc');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.inner').slideUp(200, 'easeOutCirc');
});

$.noConflict();
// Tabs
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

$.noConflict();
// PrettyPhoto
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});

$.noConflict();
// Search Button Toggle
jQuery(".menu-search-button").click(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-search-field").toggleClass("menu-search-focus", 200);
});});
```

Comment: I don't see include of jquery in your <head>, only jqueryui

Comment: You're not including scripts in wordpress correctly, this is likely to be the issue. See here for a great tutorial on using `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` to add your scripts: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

Comment: [How to Include JavaScript and CSS in Your WordPress Themes and Plugins](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)